# Load PDB for MemoryModule-loaded DLL in x64dbg

Tags: dll, x64dbg, dynamic-linking, debugging-symbols, pdb

I need to debug a DLL, which I have a PDB file for.

The debug target is a program, that loads the DLL using MemoryModule library from [Github](https://github.com/fancycode/MemoryModule).

The loaded module isn't listed as a module in x64dbg, since it has been loaded with `MemoryLoadLibraryEx` function, but module handle is still valid and it's all been successfully loaded and initialized.

I've tried `symload` x64dbg command with address as the argument pointing to the beginning of the memory-loaded module `MZ...`, tried pointing to `PE...` signature as well, but no success.

How do I tell x64dbg that memory at an address is a valid module, so that I could load a PDB for that module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

x64dbg has the [virtualmod](https://help.x64dbg.com/en/latest/commands/analysis/virtualmod.html) command, which (in theory) can be used to detect modules loaded from memory, rather than via `LoadLibrary*` APIs:

> virtualmod
>
> Tell the debugger to treat a memory range as a virtual module.
>
> Arguments: 
> `arg1` the user-supplied module name.
> `arg2` the base of the memory range.
> `[arg3]` the size of the memory range.

However, this  command seems to be broken at the time of writing this answer. I've experimented a little bit and managed to make it functional, see this [commit](https://github.com/ynwarcs/x64dbg/commit/aa0a5cd82cdb1998af2f9f020fefd86db368f2b4) in a forked repository for reference. This will allow you to see the module in x64dbg, as well as its symbols, exports, imports etc. For a fully native experience, though, a fix is needed in MemoryModule as well - see this [commit](https://github.com/ynwarcs/MemoryModule/commit/10250ad4b7ee464579dfb13605427bad1626cbd9) in a forked repository for reference.

To use it, execute the following in x64dbg:

```
virtualmod some_module_name.dll, 0xsome_base_address
```

If you don't mind building your own x64dbg and MemoryModule and applying these fixes, this should work out-of-the-box (no promises though). I've also opened [an issue](https://github.com/x64dbg/x64dbg/issues/3094) in x64dbg to discuss the state of `virtualmod` and whether it can be fixed in the main branch as well.